# How to aggregate combinations / permutations in elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, combinations, permutation, elasticsearch-painless

Is there a possibility to aggregate combinations or permutations in elasticsearch of a single field per document?

Example for combinations for 1 row:

```
keyword_field : ["test", "array", "for", "combinations"]
```

<-- aggregate -->

```
[
  [ 'test', 'array' ],
  [ 'test', 'for' ],
  [ 'test', 'combinations' ],
  [ 'array', 'for' ],
  [ 'array', 'combinations' ],
  [ 'for', 'combinations' ]
]
```

I want to calculate how often words appear together in a document. Therefore I imagine that I need to calculate combinations independend for every single document and later add them together.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a new column with [painless script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/7.0/index.html) to achieve this.

The script would work per document, but you can aggregate on the resulting column and get the stats you need.

So, you'll need to:

- use the [update_by_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-api-source) API to update the existing documents with the new columns
- Or, you could route your incomming documents through an [ingest pipeline with the painless code](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/script-processor.html) that does this
- Or, if you'd like to do this for existing and all incomming documents, then you'll need all of above

Note that a [scripted field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-script-fields.html) is not going to work, as it does not work with aggregates (last I checked)...